# hclust size limit?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining, hclust

I'm new to R. I'm trying to run hclust() on about 50K items. I have 10 columns to compare and 50K rows of data. When I tried assigning the distance matrix, I get: "Cannot allocate vector of 5GB".

Is there a size limit to this? If so, how do I go about doing a cluster of something this large?

**EDIT**

I ended up increasing the max.limit and increased the machine's memory to 8GB and that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: I wonder if you are trying to cluster the rows? If so, then you are trying to make a 50k * 50k distance matrix (2.5e9 items in the matrix). This would be larger than R allows (maximum of 2^31 - 1 items in any one vector or matrix).

Comment: I was given a dataset to work with and need to know the relationships of all of them. Is there some filter I should apply?

Comment: Hierarchical clustering, when implemented naively, is `O(n^3)` in complexity. So just don't even think of using it for large data sets.

Answer (score 5):

Classic hierarchical clustering approaches are `O(n^3)` in runtime and `O(n^2)` in memory complexity. So yes, they scale incredibly bad to large data sets. Obviously, anything that requires materialization of the distance matrix is in `O(n^2)` or worse.

Note that there are some specializations of hierarchical clustering such as SLINK and CLINK that run in `O(n^2)`, and depending on the implementation may also only need `O(n)` memory.

You might want to look into more modern clustering algorithms. Anything that runs in `O(n log n)` or better should work for you. There are plenty of good reasons to *not* use hierarchical clustering: usually it is rather sensitive to noise (i.e. it doesn't really know what to do with outliers) and the results are hard to interpret for large data sets (dendrograms are nice, but only for small data sets).

Comment: Running into similar problems as OP. Any suggestions for modern clustering algorithms?

Comment: Many people have had success with DBSCAN apparently.

Answer (score 3):

The size limit is being set by your hardware and software, and you have not given enough specifics to say much more. On a machine with adequate resources you would not be getting this error. Why not try a 10% sample before diving into the deep end of the pool? Perhaps starting with:

```
reduced <- full[ sample(1:nrow(full), nrow(full)/10 ) , ]
```